# Same type and same words, but still returns false when asked if they're the same

Tags: javascript, angular

So I'm working on a chat app with socket.io and I want to decide whether it is my message or someone else's. The two things I use for this are the full name I retrieve from the localstorage and the full name that got returned from the server when I sent a new message. Does someone know why the two are still not the same even though they're both strings and they're both consisting of the same words?

```
isItMyMsg(message){
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('fullName'));
        console.log(message.fullname);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('fullName') === message.fullName);
        return localStorage.getItem('fullName') === message.fullName
    }
```

**This is a screenshot I took that logs the results. two are the results from local storage and server object and the false is from when I assess whether they are the same. I was expecting it to return TRUE, but I got a FALSE instead**

[image]

Comment: Are there any trailing spaces?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:
1-Check if maybe somehow there are extra spaces, so do:

```
const first = localStorage.getItem('fullName').trim();
const second = message.fullName.trim();
```

Then do:

```
console.log(first === second);
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
const first = localStorage.getItem('fullName').trim().toLowerCase();
const second = message.fullname.trim().toLowerCase();
```

To see if case sensitivity makes any difference.

Comment: Yeah, there were spaces that caused it to return false, thanks!